# 'AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was not authenticated.' when Identity Server 4 hosted in IIS but work hosted in Azure

Tags: identityserver4

I am attempting to add a new mobile client using AppAuth.JS to an existing working Identity Server 4 (3.1.2)

If I host my Identity Server instance in Azure it works, but if I host it in an on-premises IIS instance (still on HTTPS with real SSL cert, not a self-signed cert) it fails with the error

> dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[9]
> AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was not authenticated.

My new client is defined as

```
new Client 
                {
                    ClientId = "< a guid>",
                    ClientName = "Android",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    RequirePkce = true,
                    RequireConsent = false,
                    RequireClientSecret = false,
                    ClientSecrets = 
                    {
                        new Secret("<a guid>".Sha256())
                    },
                    RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,
                    RedirectUris = { "net.openid.appauth:/oauth2redirect" },
                    AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "offline_access"},
                    AllowOfflineAccess = true
                },
```

Does anyone have any idea why this works in Azure but not ISS?

Is it likely to be an IIS configuration or Identity Server configuration issue?

As requested here are the key sections of the `startup.cs`

The startup class is as follows

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
    services.AddOptions();
    services.Configure<MySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MySettings"));

    // Configure identity server
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
    _logger.LogInformation("Looged from Configure");

    var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddProfileService<MyProfileService>();

    // fix for same site cookies in Chrome 80
    services.ConfigureNonBreakingSameSiteCookies();
    services.AddTransient<IProfileService, CCCProfileService>();

    builder.AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients());
               
    builder.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources());
    // use the dev cert for testing
    builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // Initialise the grant and operational databases (all in memory for testing)
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseIdentityServer();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
       routes.MapRoute("login", "account/login", defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login" });
       routes.MapRoute("logout", "account/logout", defaults: new { controller = "Logout", action = "Logout" });
       routes.MapRoute("register", "account/register", defaults: new { controller = "Register", action = "Register" });
       routes.MapRoute("forgottenpassword", "account/forgottenpassword", defaults: new { controller = "ForgottenPassword", action = "ForgottenPassword" });
       routes.MapRoute("resetpassword", "account/resetpassword/{secret}", defaults: new { controller = "ForgottenPassword", action = "ResetPassword" });
       routes.MapRoute("error", "home/error", defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Error" });
       routes.MapRoute("default", string.Empty, defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
      });
}
```

Comment: I would explore the requests in Fiddler to explore where it fails. you could also post the backend startup class to the question. The exception is from IdentityServer, right? A bit hard to give any clear answers without more details.  I would also try to increase the log level in identityServer to debug, to better get an idea why it fails.

Comment: The code in ASP.NET that creates this exception is found here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/e61245a09a5a998bf06d6054734e00e9cf068a28/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/AuthenticationHandler.cs#L204

Comment: I have added the `startup.cs` key methods to the above issue

Comment: In the Configure method I would add a UseAuthorization() call after the call to   app.UseIdentityServer();

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I tried adding `UseAuthorization()` it made no difference.

Comment: Detailed logging shows the difference in a working flow (Azure) and the failing (IIS or kestrel) is a nonce in the in authorise/callback

`/connect/authorize/callback?redirect_uri=net.openid.appauth%3A%2Foauth2redirect&client_id=<guid>&response_type=code&state=<string>&nonce=Z-YxOFp6gCu2XU8dPSlx8w&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access&code_challenge=<string>&code_challenge_method=S256`
The presence of the nonce seems to lose cause the loss of the idsvr authentication.

Any suggestions as to why the nonce is causing the issue?

Comment: are you using load-balancing?

Comment: The production system where I first found the problem is load balanced (behind an F5 load balancer). However, in an attempt to isolate the problem I have stripped back my test system to a locally hosted single instance (kestrel with https) and an AppAuth.JS client in an Android emulator. The exactly same code I am using locally works in Azure. hence my confusion

Comment: My personal recommendation to create sanity, is to put IdentityServer in its own service, do all client OpenIDConnect handling in the backend (Separate ASP.NET Core project) and just use session cookies with your JavaScript client.

Comment: Your problem is perhaps due to CORS or SameSite cookies? do check the browser console for hints. Also use tools like Fiddler to examine the HTTP traffic and try to figure out what request is failing, and post it here.

Comment: Yes, my reading is all pointing to similar areas. I will see what Fiddler shows. Thanks for all the help

Comment: I have been looking into the /account/login call with Fiddler. A suspected, the issue seems to be that the `idsrv` and `idsrv.session` cookies are being sent in the response to the android appAuth client, set as secure and samesite=none, but they are not being saved. hence the loop is caused.

Still need to work out why

Comment: Are you sure you are using HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, I only have port 443 bound to my Identity Server and it is running a 'real' SSL cert, not a developer on, so there are no trust issues over the cert or its root authority

Comment: can you reach IdentityServer and its discovery document in your browser when you host it behind IIS?  perhaps it is CORS? inside IIS? and if CORS, you need to make sure Options work in IIS.

Comment: Yes, I can reach the weel know document `https://test.mydoman.co.uk/.well-known/openid-configuration` and see all the expected results. I will look more into the CORS settings

Comment: you could always as a test try to integrate against https://demo.identityserver.io/ to evaluate if it is your backend or the app that is causing the problem. you could in your app try to use the same login as used there.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem, it was down to the order in the startup.cs file. Seems Azure is far more forgiving when IIS/Kestrel. This order worked

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // needs to be before everything else
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    // Initialise the grant and operational databases
    this.InitializeDatabase(app);

    app.UseIdentityServer();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        // the routes
    });
}
```

I had had the UseCookiePolicy too late in the flow.

Thanks, @Tore for all the suggestion to get me an answer